# How can I replace NaN values based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got 3 columns in a pandas dataframe. These are columns A, B, and C.

```
data = {"A": [10,12,30,21],
        "B": [12,24,16,31],
        "C": [1,None,None,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
print(df)
```

I want to replace NaN values in column C based on the data in column B, such that:

- if the value in B is between 10 and 20, I want to replace the NaN value in column C with 1,
- if the value in B is between 20 and 30, I want to replace the NaN value in column C with 2,
- if the value in B is between 30 and 40 , I want to replace the NaN value in column C with 3,

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `replacement_value: index_mask` mapping using a dictionary and then iterate over it, like so:

```py
>>> masks = {1: (df['B'] >= 10) & (df['B'] < 20) & df['C'].isnull(), 2: (df['B'] >= 20) & (df['B'] < 30) & df['C'].isnull(), 3: (df['B'] >= 30) & df['C'].isnull()}
>>> masks
{1: 0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool, 2: 0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool, 3: 0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool}
>>> for replacement_value, mask in masks.items():
...     df.loc[mask, 'C'] = replacement_value
... 
>>> df
    A   B    C
0  10  12  1.0
1  12  24  2.0
2  30  16  1.0
3  21  31  4.0
```

Note that I made the between conditions exclusive on the upper bound, i.e. to replace with 1 the value for `df['B']` needs to be in the range `[10, 20)]`; to replace with 2 `[20, 30)`, etc., because otherwise you have overlapping bounds.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for your help! Just want to make sure though, this doesn't just replace the missing values right? It just generates the correct category value for all the rows even if a value was already assigned.

Comment: In a way, yes. The `df['C'].isnull()` condition ensures that the only rows affected by this procedure are null.

Comment: Feel free to hit the check mark next to the voting options to mark this as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
import numpy as np
df['C'].loc[(df['B']<=10) & (df['B']>=1) & (df['C'].isnull())]=1
df['C'].loc[(df['B']<=20) & (df['B']>=11) & (df['C'].isnull())]=2
```

Comment: Tried this, it just returned empty columns. Which part of the code here specifies which columns values are meant to me changed?

Comment: can you try : `print(df.loc[(df['b']<=10) & (df['b']>=1) & (df['c']==np.nan)]) ` ?

Comment: This is what I get:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []

Comment: oh, in your definition of df, you have none types, not NaN, can you try again with my edited version ?

Comment: Tried the edited version, the values still appear as NaN.

Comment: @NHL, you're not assigning to `'C'` in your `.loc` call.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need the `df['c'] is None` – it should be `df['c'].isnull()`.